# Question about a simple PHP Autoloader

Tags: php, namespaces, autoload

I was just learning aboutt PHP namespaces and starting to create a simple autoload function. What O did was:

```
function __autoload($name) {
  echo $name . "<br />";
  require_once $name . ".php";
}
```

So, this works if I do not use any aliasing or importing statements eg. `use MainNamespace\Subnamespace` because if I did that, assuming i have:

```
\GreatApp\Models\User.php
\GreatApp\Models\Project.php
\GreatApp\Util\Util.php
\GreatApp\Util\Test\Test.php
```

if I try to do:

```
new GreatApp\Models\User();
```

it works because `$name` in autoload will become `GreatApp\Models\User` so `GreatApp\Models\User.php` is found. But when I do:

```
use GreatApp\Models;
new User();
```

it fails because now `$name` is just `User` and `User.php` will not be found. How should I setup autoloading then?

Comment: You should use spl_autoload_register instead of the __autoload function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Full namespace path is always passed to the autoloader no matter how you import namespace and reference a class. It should work.

**Just the __autoload function itself should belong to main (root) namespace**

Comment: Please read PHP docs on how namespaces work. When you try to reference a class using "Test\Test" it actually means you a referencing \current-namespace\Test\Test. current-namespace is the namespace of the file from where you are referencing. "use" does not change current namespace. It just imports another namespace to use from within current.

Comment: for better understanding of namespace follow this link
http://www.sitepoint.com/php-53-namespaces-basics/